# how to change multiple nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i'm doing a course system, and i would like to simplify the routes.

i routed like this:

```
resources :courses do
    resources :modules do
      resources :lesson
    end
end
```

and returned this:

```
/courses/:course_id/modules/:module_id/lesson/:id
/courses/:course_id/modules/:id
/courses/:id
etc...
```

i want my routes like that:

```
/courses/:course_name/:module_name/:lesson_name
/courses/:course_name/:module_name/
/courses/:course_name/
etc...
```

but how?! :(

Comment: Have you ever use friendly_id ?? check out this https://github.com/norman/friendly_id and http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: nice! works beautiful! but i still getting:

`/courses/:course_id/modules/:module_id/lesson/:lesson_id`

i want to exclude the MODULE and LESSON path, keeping just the name of these:

`/courses/:course_id/:module_id/:lesson_id`

Answer (score 0):

in the routes file

`get "/courses/:course_name/:module_name/:lesson_name", as: :courses`

then you should be able to generate the path:

`courses_path(course_name: course.name, module_name: module.name, lesson_name: lesson.name)`

But I would recommend against it as:

1) This is fighting conventions: don't expect good support for this, none of the new developers who join the project will like you for this.

2) You will have to make sure all course/module/lesson names are unique and url-friendly

3) You'll have to make sure the names never change, because then the urls would change.

I would advice sticking to the default nested paths and overriding #to_param on every module 
to smth like:

`def to_param
  "#{super}-#{name.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')}" # you need a better regex here
end`

so the urls look like

`/courses/33-computer-science/modules/23-engineering/lesson/56-design-patterns`

More about custom routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments